# In a custom task in Gradle how can I use a class from a dependency

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I have a custom gradle kotlin task like below. How can I access the SomeLibraryClass class. That class lives in a jar file which I have declared as a dependency but it's not visible to the task.

```
tasks.register("my-task") {
    doLast {
        SomeLibraryClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you declare it as a buildscript dependency?

Comment: I tried that initially bit it wasn't accessible. The issue turned out to be caused by the jar file. Other jar files worked fine. I will reply to this question just in case anyone else has this question.